# Windows Server update - noncritical update installation with delay

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, update, scheduled-task

Is it possible set automatically update installation with delay from publish date?? For example, install it 1 month later. 
I want to set it only for not-critical security updates at Windows Server 2012 R2.

My reason is that MS often release an update without support by another MS software, or this updates has a bug and later are take back.

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

There are no native Windows Update settings that will allow you to do this AFAIK. You could deploy a WSUS server which would allow you to approve and install updates only after you've tested them.

Comment: Thx, I will try to browse WSUS API documentation and perhaps to create an application or script.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do it automatically in WSUS based on a date after release either.
either do it automatically by windows update or WSUS or you need to do it manually or with third party tools